# Dynamically add options to a choice% box in racket

Tags: user-interface, racket

In Racket, I can create a choice box with:

```
(define f (new frame% [label "HI"]))
(define my-box
  (new choice% [parent f]
               [label "Some choices"]
               [choices (list "Choice A" "Choice B")]))
```

And I will get a window that looks something like this:

[image: Example Window]

The problem is that I have to build the `choices` field at the same time that the `choice%` class is created. Is there any way I can dynamically add items to the list after the box is created, without the need to remove the box entirely and add a new one with the new choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically add and remove items to the list because `choice%` boxes implement the [`list-control<%>`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/list-control___.html?q=list-control) interface. This functionality is broken out into a common interface because `list-box%` classes have very similar needs.

This gives you the ability to `append`, `clear`, and `delete` items in the list. As well as query the index of the list and the value there.

As an example, the following program adds one list item per 5 seconds or so, for the first 50 (or so) seconds of the program:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define f (new frame% [label "HI"]))
(define my-box
  (new choice% [parent f]
       [label "Some choices"]
       [choices '()]))

(thread
 (λ ()
   (for ([i (in-range 10)])
     (send my-box append (number->string i))
     (sleep 5))))

(send f show #t)
```

There is one catch to be aware of however, the initial list is used to set the choice%'s width. So you will either want to set that manually with `min-width`, or initially populate it with the widest possible element which you immediate clear.